# An unhandlable error occured

Tags: 16.04, package-management, disk-usage

I can't achieve updates, I get the following message (see image).

[image]

```
$ df -h
Filesystem       Size  Used Avail Use%   Mounted on
udev             1,9G     0  1,9G   0%   /dev 
tmpfs            384M   11M  373M   3%   /run 
/dev/sda5         20G   18G  1,3G  94%   /
tmpfs            1,9G  1,1M  1,9G   1%   /dev/shm 
tmpfs            5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1%   /run/lock 
tmpfs            1,9G     0  1,9G   0%   /sys/fs/cgroup 
/dev/sda6        133G   41G   86G  32%   /home 
cgmfs            100K     0  100K   0%   /run/cgmanager/fs 
tmpfs            384M   72K  384M   1%   /run/user/1001
```

i don't want to do a new partition. how can i move unuseful files? how can i add partition via terminal?

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a dpkg: error: unable to create new file '/var/lib/dpkg/status-new': No space left on device
```

Comment: Run `df -h` add the output to your question.

Comment: See the part that says 'No space left on device'?  Do you understand what that means?

Comment: the out put of df -h {Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1,9G     0  1,9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           384M   11M  373M   3% /run
/dev/sda5        20G   18G  1,3G  94% /
tmpfs           1,9G  1,1M  1,9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1,9G     0  1,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda6       133G   41G   86G  32% /home
cgmfs           100K     0  100K   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs           384M   72K  384M   1% /run/user/1001
}

Comment: @karel i don't want to do a new partition,  how can i move unuseful files ?

Comment: how can i add partition via terminal ?

Comment: '  sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: error: unable to create new file '/var/lib/dpkg/status-new': No space left on device'

Comment: I need some time to discuss this matter with another user who wrote in a book about this topic.

Comment: @karel ok, in fact i had this problem before and i resolved it  http://paste.ubuntu.com/23665800/ then i tried this command '  sudo dpkg --remove linux-headers-4.4.0-36 linux-headers-4.4.0-36-generic  ' then this command '  sudo apt install linux-headers-4.4.0-57 linux-headers-4.4.0-57-generic  ' but now this doesn't work ! the problem that this block other programs .

Comment: Maybe `sudo apt autoremove` can free up some disk space. The current latest kernel version in 16.04 is 4.4.0-77-generic.